# Issue showing a DataGridView from an array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, datagridview

Has anyone heard of the following issue?

I created an array of DataGridView and I am successfully filling them with information (verified in a data dump).
However when I try to display the DataGridViews, even when I made sure size, location and visibility were all set, the DataGridView table wasn’t show up in my `form1`.

When I use the DataGridView normally (created and compiled) it works.
Those were the settings I used to set the run-time creations of the array of DataGridViews.

If you really need to see my code I can post it.
I am just looking for ideas of where I haven’t figured out to look yet.
I like to figure stuff out on my own as much as possible but I’ve been stuck for a couple days now.

I’m guessing it’s because of the array and not because I created the dgv at runtime.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: without code thats not possible to answer. However one suggestion: Why not reuse the same datagrid and just swap out the DataSource? Just use DataTables to hold the data for example.

Comment: I’ll try that and let you know!  Thanks. :)

Comment: DGV don't automatically get repainted when data gets changed.  Since you aren't getting any errors it seems like you have a display issue.  The trick in getting DGV updated is to set DataSource to null and then back to actual data : datagridview1.DataSource = null; datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: Your code is needed. You should also explain what *normally* means in: *When I use the DataGridView normally*. Or what *abnormal* would be in comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks T.Schwarz.  That worked as I wanted!

I apologize to all for not posting code.  As I stated I like to figure out things and I wasn’t looking to get others to do my code for me.  I guess everyone needs to see what I was doing to understand why I was having a problem.   My second post will be much more informative.   Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.